# API Gateway and DynamoDB PutItem for String Set

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I can't seem to find how to correctly call PutItem for a StringSet in DynamoDB through API Gateway. If I call it like I would for a List of Maps, then I get objects returned. Example data is below.

```
{
    "eventId": "Lorem",
    "eventName": "Lorem",
    "companies": [
        {
            "companyId": "Lorem",
            "companyName": "Lorem"
        }
    ],
    "eventTags": [
        "Lorem",
        "Lorem"
    ]
}
```

And my example template call for companies:

```
"companies" : {
     "L": [
          #foreach($elem in $inputRoot.companies) {
            "M": {
              "companyId": {
                "S": "$elem.companyId"
              },
              "companyName": {
                "S": "$elem.companyName"
              }
            }
        } #if($foreach.hasNext),#end
        #end
     ]
}
```

I've tried to call it with String Set listed, but it errors out still and tells me that "Start of structure or map found where not expected" or that serialization failed.

```
"eventTags" : {
      "SS": [
        #foreach($elem in $inputRoot.eventTags) {
           "S":"$elem"
        } #if($foreach.hasNext),#end
        #end
      ]
    }
```

What is the proper way to call PutItem for converting an array of strings to a String Set?

Comment: Are you using javascript?

Comment: I'm doing this directly through the body template in API gateway. I'm just specifying a format of application/json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using JavaScript AWS SDK, you can use document client API (docClient.createSet) to store the SET data type.

**docClient.createSet**  - converts the array into SET data type

```
var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();   

     var params = {
    TableName:table,
    Item:{
        "yearkey": year,
        "title": title       
        "product" : docClient.createSet(['milk','veg'])        
    }
};
```

Comment: I ended up going this route and using the JavaScript SDK in Lambda instead. Thanks!